# Build JSON with multiple arrays in Groovy

Tags: json, grails, jackson, jsonbuilder

Can anyone please help me in building JSON in the format below?

```
{
    "hid": 5000607,
    "eid": "mpuli243",
    "lud": 1488299449000,
    "ats": [{
        "ac": ["CCLA0004"],
        "lud": 1488296135092,
        "prem": "Y",
        "pr": [{
            "isDefaultBoolean": true,
            "a": 11.0,
            "pid": 1,
            "ct": 1488299449000,
            "lud": 1488299449000,
            "d": "Y",
            "s": [{
                "sd": 1488171600000,
                "ed": 253402232400000,
                "DOW": ["SU",
                "MO",
                "TU",
                "WE",
                "TH",
                "SA"],
                "lud": 1488299449000
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

erm....

```
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()

def json = jsonSlurper.parseText('{ "hid": 5000607, "eid": "mpuli243", "lud": 1488299449000, "ats": [{ "ac": ["CCLA0004"], "lud": 1488296135092, "prem": "Y", "pr": [{ "isDefaultBoolean": true, "a": 11.0, "pid": 1, "ct": 1488299449000, "lud": 1488299449000, "d": "Y", "s": [{ "sd": 1488171600000, "ed": 253402232400000, "DOW": ["SU", "MO", "TU", "WE", "TH", "SA"], "lud": 1488299449000 }] }] }] }')
```

?

Or could you elaborate some more about the difficulties you are facing generating this. What have you tried? What worked? What did not ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the question was edited... but this is valid json:

```js
var json  = {
    "hid": 5000607,
    "eid": "mpuli243",
    "lud": 1488299449000,
    "ats": [{
        "ac": ["CCLA0004"],
        "lud": 1488296135092,
        "prem": "Y",
        "pr": [{
            "isDefaultBoolean": true,
            "a": 11.0,
            "pid": 1,
            "ct": 1488299449000,
            "lud": 1488299449000,
            "d": "Y",
            "s": [{
                "sd": 1488171600000,
                "ed": 253402232400000,
                "DOW": ["SU",
                "MO",
                "TU",
                "WE",
                "TH",
                "SA"],
                "lud": 1488299449000
            }]
        }]
    }]
};

console.log(json["hid"]);
$(foo).html(json["hid"]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
</div>
```

... from the post. Jquery included only for ease of use.